# Eclipse CDT: How to use GCC C++ compiler on C sources?

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, visual-studio

I have a C++ project in which I need to use some external C sources.
I need to compile them with the same Tool as the project uses: GCC C++ compiler.

I Visual Studio there is a setting to set this for each C source: C/C++ -> Advanced -> Compile as C++ Code (/TP).

Can I do this with Eclipse CDT ?

Comment: Yes, just create c++ project or set g++ compiler in build project properties

Comment: You cannot generally compile C code with a C++ compiler as C is not a subset of C++. For example, `int *p = malloc(sizeof *p);` is legal C, but not C++.

Comment: @BaummitAugen i think you are wrong. You can use malloc or any other c function in c++ and compile it with g++.

Comment: @clsbartek read closer, and perhaps try it

Comment: @clsbartek Of course you can use `malloc()` in both languages, but that wasn't Baum's point. The syntax is legal in one language, but not in the other.

Comment: @clsbartek, I have already the C++ project created and there is selected the GCC C++ Compiler but for the external C sources Eclipse uses GCC C Compiler and I cannot change this to GCC C++ Compiler.

Comment: @sehe ok, now i get it. It depends on syntax, you are right. Bu still you can compile it with any compiler. You just get an syntax error :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In project options:

1. You could add `-x c++` to the compiler flags:

   [image]
2. Alternatively set the tool to g++ instead of gcc

   [image]

Comment: Thank very much for this two solutions. There is also the possibility to get rid of this kind of error in the mentioned C code ? `#if UNIX_PLATFORM && !defined(__cplusplus)
#error This file needs to be compiled as C++ on Unix
#endif` <-- this still gives me an error for `__cplusplus not defined`

Comment: As you could see in my live stream, the #error doesn't trigger with `-x c++`. It does without. Good luck